# LineChart of th achartengine library: the x point doesn't match with the y one

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a problem with the visualization of a line graph, as you can see in the chart the x poins don't match exactly with the y point, they are slighty righter.

On Apr 12, 2012 the x value must be exactly 2

On Apr 13, 2012 the x value must be exactly 3

On Apr 16, 2012 the x value must be exactly 6

Has anyone else met my same proplem?
Can someone help me?

[image]

My code is very simple, I have a list of object, each element of which contains both data value and int value and I put these value in the two different arrays that will be used to draw the chart. I'm using achartengine-07 library.

```
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer aRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        Date[] x = new Date[list.size()]; 
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
            x[j] = list.get(j).getData();
        }

        int[] y = new int[list.size()]; 
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
            y[j] =Integer.parseInt(list.get(j).getRank());
        }

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(h[i]);
        for(int k = 0; k <x.length; k++)
            series.add(x[k], y[k]);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        aRenderer.setXLabels(x.length);
        aRenderer.setYLabels(y.length);
        aRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The time chart in AChartEngine tries to compute the best "rounded" labels like everyday midnight or so.

If you don't like this approach, you could build a regular line chart with custom labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I builded a regular line chart, like suggested by Dan, with custom labels and to remove the previous label I put setXLabels(0):

```
      aRenderer.addXTextLabel();
      // To remove the previous label put
      aRenderer.setXLabels(0);
```